# WPF Listview Item Vertical Positioning with Canvas Overlap Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, canvas, word-addins

I have a word addin which has a **WPF** custom task pane. In that I have a `Listview`. I need to dynamicaly update the position of each `listview` item when word document scroll down. but some of them can be having same `canvas.top(vertical Y)` value.Then those items getting overlap.

I do not need to overlap those,I need as listview need to align one after another.

[screen sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZEwR.png)

Code Sample XAML..

```
<listViewTool:ListView x:Name="Results" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="WhiteSmoke"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"                      
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Results}"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
    <listViewTool:ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Margin" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},Path=ActualWidth}" />
        </Style>
    </listViewTool:ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <listViewTool:ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas x:Name="CanvasMain" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type ListView}},Path=ActuaHeight}"
                            ClipToBounds="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </listViewTool:ListView.ItemsPanel>
</listViewTool:ListView>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Code? Screenshot? Anything to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: I updated the question with screenshot and code sample.

Comment: Hi Sinatr,Did you get the question?

Comment: It's still not very clear what is the problem. Where is overlap? Can you mark the problem and show how you want it to be?

Comment: When I clicked listview item because of canvas overlay happen, the expander text displayed behind second item you can see in second attachment. What I want is when click the item the below item will be go down automatically to give space to clicked one. See the screenshot.

Comment: Why are you using `Canvas` as `ItemsPanel` ? What you want is a behavior of `StackPanel` (it will automatically re-layout children when size of either will change).

Comment: In stackpanel can I have dynamically update the listview item positions? That is why I used canvas. Canvas can update the Y postion as below. <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>

Comment: You can create own `Panel` which will combine behavior of `Canvas` (to use absolute coordinates) and `StackPanel` (to correct overlapped elements). The easiest solution is probably to recalculate position for each element when collapsed state of any item is changed. You can introduce `YOffset` which is reset to `0` for each item, then iterate over list of items, find overlapped item and set `YOffset` for it and any further item.

Comment: Can you help me on this development how to initiate this? I did some stuff using this reference. but failed.  http://ikeptwalking.com/wpf-measureoverride-arrangeoverride-explained/

Comment: Me and others may try if you prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or you want a generic answer?

Comment: Hi Sinatr,Generic answer is better, then i ll try my best first. For your reference: The listview item each one is having 30 height if it clicks it will get different height with content inside.If you need for clarification let me know.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a simple solution, which looks like this:

[image]

---

Idea is to store height of items and recalculate position of all items when height of either is changed.

Item height is item template border `ActualHeight`. For each item: `Y` is initial position, `Offset` is calculated/used to bind (based on `Height` of items before current item).

Solution contains some debugging code (`Text` property and binding) and is not a pure MVVM (but you didn't ask for one):

xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left"
                    Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top"
                    Value="{Binding Offset}" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Border CornerRadius="10"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                BorderBrush="Gray"
                                SizeChanged="Border_SizeChanged">
                            <Expander Header="{Binding Text}">
                                <Grid Height="50" />
                            </Expander>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}"
                    ClipToBounds="True" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

cs:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "") =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

    public double Y { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }

    double _offset;
    public double Offset
    {
        get { return _offset; }
        set
        {
            _offset = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Text));
        }
    }

    public string Text => $"Y={Y} Height={Height} Offset={Offset}";
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            Items.Add(new Item { Y = i * 40 });
        DataContext = this;
    }

    void Border_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = (Border)sender;
        var current = (Item)border.DataContext;
        current.Height = border.ActualHeight;
        // recalculate offset
        var y = Items[0].Y;
        foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            item.Offset = y > item.Y ? y : item.Y;
            y = item.Offset + item.Height;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution is seems ok and working fine,I am going to apply this kind of solution.Thanks a lot Sanatr.